# Real roots of $3^{x} + 4^{x} = 5^{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How do I show that $3^{x}+4^{x} = 5^{x}$ has exactly one real root.

Comment: Side note: complex solutions $x$ can also be studied.  (Michael Lapidus has a book on "complex dimensions".)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hints:

- Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \biggl(\frac{3}{5}\biggr)^{x} + \biggl(\frac{4}{5}\biggr)^{x} -1$
- Note : $f'(x) < 0$ and $f(2)=0$. Apply [Rolle's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 10):

Rewrite our equation as 
$$\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x=1.$$
We have the familiar solution $x=2$.

If $x>2$, then $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x \lt \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2$ and 
$\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x \lt \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2$, and therefore
$$\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x \lt 1.$$
Similarly, if $x<2$ then $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x \gt \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2$
and $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x \gt \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2$, so
$$\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x \gt 1.$$

Comment: Ah nice. It's elementary

Answer (score 3):

Consider our equation as: 
$$\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x=1.$$

Notice that left side is a sum of 2 monotonically decreasing functions and their sum is a monotonically decreasing function. Hence, the only possible solution is x=2.

The proof is complete.

Comment: Do not say "nonincreasing", since there could be multiple solutions for nonincreasing function in general.  Instead say "decreasing".

Comment: @GEdgar: you're right. OK.